# Why does rendering to one slot remove renders from other slots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

In Cycles render I used to render multiple images to multiple slots to compare results.
But now rendering to one slot clears the other slots.

Is there a setting I need to fix this?  So I can render to all the different slots and the images stay there?

[image]

Comment: Which version is this? I haven't experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to click the blank button to right of Slot 1.
Then select the render.
It was there, just hiding.

[image]